# Send e-mail from a Java desktop application

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm investigating what is the best way to go, in order to implement the functionality to send a plain text e-mail from a Java desktop application (cross platform, Linux, Win and Mac).

Basically I'm exploring the javax.mail API and I'm considering the following three options;

1. Through the javax.mail API using gmail SMTP server

   *This option is the most easy to implement, however I think security wise it is not a   good option because the SMTP server password needs to be embedded into the code (Any jar file can be decompiled, hence the danger of exposing the password).*
2. Through the javax.mail API using a local SMTP server

   *Security wise this would be ok. however it would require a client machine with a running SMTP server, I cannot assume all my users have a SMTP server running.*
3. Through the javax.mail API which uses an application instantiated SMTP server

   *Portability wise and security wise this seems the best option. However this is also looks like a lot of work and is probably more easy said than done, hence I'm not sure if this is a feasible option.*

Obviously none of the three options are really satisfying and I wonder if I'm missing something obvious here, hence the reason for my question. Is there any reasonable way (regarding security, portability and amount of work needed) to implement this functionallity.

Comment: You can't run an SMTP server on most home ISPs.  You should talk to your own server and validate requests to prevent spammers.

Comment: [Gmail supports OAuth 2.0 for SMTP authentication](https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview). That might help with the security issue in option 1.

Comment: This is an interesting question, regarding the first item I think you could encrypt a property file to hide the API key and secret in the authentication step of the e-mail.